# Remove duplicate values from array - array_unique() not working

Tags: php, arrays, image, web-scraping

I have a script that's scraping images from a website (4chan). It's having to do it by getting the url from the anchor tags not the image, else it would only get the thumbnails. The problem is that the url for the image appears in two anchor tags, thus each image appears twice.

I've tried putting them into an array and then applying array_unique() but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->href, "/src/")){
    $a = $element->href;    
    $ht = "<img src=\"" . $a. "\" />\n";
    $arr = array($ht);
    $arr = array_unique($arr);
    foreach($arr as &$b) {
            echo $b;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding to an array, you are redefining `$arr` on every iteration. Try this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->href, "/src/")){
        $a = $element->href;    
        $ht = "<img src=\"" . $a. "\" />\n";
        $arr[] = $ht; 
    }
}
$arr = array_unique($arr);
foreach($arr as &$b) {
    echo $b;
}
```

Comment: Gives a lot of errors, all seem to be stemming from: Undefined variable: arr

Comment: This increases the amount of duplicates

Comment: By which I mean, this happens: http://aviatex14.co.uk/apps/4cpv.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fboards.4chan.org%2Fpo%2Fres%2F464208&submit=Go+%3E+%3E

Comment: My code (and your original code) was missing a closing `}`. Fixed now. From your link, it looks like 4chan is detecting you're trying to leech their images, and serving that standard logo instead.

Comment: Works a charm, much appreciated, and as for 4chan detecting, I can't see that, however they don't block stuff like that due to all the archiving sites :) Thanks for the help :P